# What's the intention behind such kind of template partial specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, specialization, sgi

when I tried to reconstruct the SGI STL source code, I saw this code snippet

```cpp
template <class _Func, class _Ret>
struct _STL_GENERATOR_ERROR {
  static _Ret __generator_requirement_violation(_Func& __f) {
    return __f();
  }
};
template <class _Func>
struct _STL_GENERATOR_ERROR<_Func, void> {
  static void __generator_requirement_violation(_Func& __f) {
    return __f();
  }
};
```

which was used to check the validity of the type of the relevant function signatures.

Here is my question:
Why SGI intentionally specialized the case of void as return type ?

```
template <class _Func, class _Ret>
struct _STL_GENERATOR_ERROR {
  static _Ret __generator_requirement_violation (_Func& __f) {
    return __f();
  }
};

void hello() {}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  void (*ptr)() = &hello;
  _STL_GENERATOR_ERROR<void(*)(), void>::__generator_requirement_violation(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

My test code could normally pass the compiling (clang/llvm/x86_64), and normally run.

If I made mistake on either understanding the original code snipped or on the design of my test case, feel free to point it out!

Big thx.

Problem Solved, but
FOLLOW UP: why my test case can handle the case of return void type?

Comment: Does the partial specialization you ask about actually use `return __f();` or `__f();`? It seems that `return __f();` would make the explicit partial specialization redundant to the generic implementation (they seem identical to me).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The source code use `return __f()` for the case of non-void-returning(__f() is non-void-returning), and simply invoke `__f()` for the case of void-returning, but what i am trying to figure out is, even I use `return __f()` for the case of void-returning, it still works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Even though returning a void expression from a void-returning function is legal C++ since ISO 98<sup>1</sup>, we can imagine some early C++ compilers had not that feature implemented.

On such compiler, the generic template would cause an error for `_Ret` = `void`:

```
template <class _Func, class _Ret>
struct _STL_GENERATOR_ERROR {
  static _Ret __generator_requirement_violation(_Func& __f) {
    return __f();
  }
};
```

This is why we can guess a specialization was added (STL is *old*):

```
template <class _Func>
struct _STL_GENERATOR_ERROR<_Func, void> {
  static void __generator_requirement_violation(_Func& __f) {
    __f();
  }
};
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> #### [stmt.return]/3
>
> A return statement with an expression of type *"cv-void"* can be used only in functions with a return *type-of-cv-void*; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.
>
> [source (p.98)](http://www.lirmm.fr/%7Educour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf)

Comment: I didn't notice this was *actually* an STL question. There may also be a use case for the partial specialization to allow using the function with `_Ret` as `void` while `_Func` is a function type with a non-`void` return type. This way you could use a function with any return type when the return value is ignored. However, I'm not sure what the template is actually used for so this case may not actually be relevant.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right. That guess is worth an answer on its own.

Comment: OP's question shows the template specialization as returning with `return __f();`. This seems like an error to me, but if it is the case than my proposed use case would not work. I've left a comment hoping for clarification.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's a typo if that [other source](http://labmaster.mi.infn.it/Laboratorio2/serale/www.sgi.com/tech/stl/concept_checks.h) is right.